# does a java thread releases the lock when time slice ends

Tags: java, multithreading, locking

```
 synchronized(objectA)   
{  
//line 1    
//line 2   
//line 3   
//line 4  
}
```

suppose the **time slice** allocated to the thread **ends** on line 3.
Will the lock acquired by this thread on objectA be released?????

Comment: What time slice? The lock is released when the `synchronized` block ends, or during a method call such as [`wait()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait--).

Comment: lock will be released only after completion of the synchronized block.

Answer (score 1):

It is released when you leave the synchronized block at the end of line 5.  A separate thread gaining access to the block of code from another timeslice will be prevented from entering the entire synchronized block until the original thread becomes active again and leaves the block.

Comment: That is not the only way the lock is released.

Comment: "*the* entire synchronized block"? Or just *any* synchronized block on the same object?

Comment: @Andreas I suppose if the thread is interrupted...  Are you thinking of something else?

Comment: I was thinking about what I said in [my comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43907005/does-a-java-thread-releases-the-lock-when-time-slice-ends/43907118?noredirect=1#comment74847385_43907005), i.e. the object can also be release *during* a method call such as `wait()`.

Comment: Oops, yes and yes, other synchronized blocks on the same object and wait() too.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, if we are defining time out using tryLock, Then yes it will release the lock after the specified time. This features help in avoiding deadlock between threads.

```
Lock lock = null;
lock=....;
if (lock.tryLock(15L, TimeUnit.SECONDS)) {
    try {
       ........
    } finally {
        lock.unlock();
    }
} else {
      // do sumthing
}
```

Comment: Question is about a `synchronized` block, so answering about code that doesn't use a synchronized block is not really relevant.

Comment: You can either use synchronize key work on Lock class for the thread safety. refer http://winterbe.com/posts/2015/04/30/java8-concurrency-tutorial-synchronized-locks-examples/

Comment: Sure you can, or one of the many other classes can be used too, but *this question* is about a the *monitor* locking mechanism of a `synchronized` block, not about all the other concurrency classes of Java.